# How to solve series of 8 equations with 8 unknowns?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

In this article http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bilinearwarp/FourCornerImageWarp2.pdf

they speak of solving for `a0,a1,a2,a3,b0,b1,b2,b3` but I want to know how exactly.

If I substitute the 4 corner coordinates I get

$0 = a0 + a1(52) + a2(0) + a3(52)(0)$

$0 = b0 + b1(52) + b2(0) + b3(52)(0)$

$256 = a0 + a1(228) + a2(46) + a3(228)(46)$

$0 = b0 + b1(228) + b2(46) + b3(228)(46)$

$0 = a0 + a1(255) + a2(229) + a3(255)(229)$

$256 = b0 + b1(255) + b2(229) + b3(255)(229)$

$256 = a0 + a1(0) + a2(246) + a3(0)(246)$

$256 = b0 + b1(0) + b2(246) + b3(0)(246)$

`[1 X0 Y0 X0Y0 0 0 0 0][a0] [0]
[1 X1 Y1 X1Y1 0 0 0 0][a1] [0]
[1 X2 Y2 X2Y2 0 0 0 0][a2] [256]
[1 X3 Y3 X3Y3 0 0 0 0][a3] [0]
[0 0 0 0 1 X0 Y0 X0Y0][b0]=[0]
[0 0 0 0 1 X1 Y1 X1Y1][b1] [256]
[0 0 0 0 1 X2 Y2 X2Y2][b2] [256]
[0 0 0 0 1 X3 Y3 X3Y3][b3] [256]`

I know I can probably solve this manually, but in general is there an algorithm that can solve this since I have to code it?

Comment: Gaussian elimination would work.  Also known as elementary row operations.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation). You should especially look at the `\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}` command:
$$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$$

Comment: This is just a system of linear equations. There are a lot of ways to solve it: some [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Solving_a_linear_system), others quite complicated (and those are the basis for the algorithms implemented in many computer algebra systems).

Comment: So you have two independent $4 \times 4$ systems (the a's and the b's), so solving will be easier than a general $8 \times 8$ system.

Comment: yes, is there a formula that can solve the 4x4?

Comment: If you are going to program it, the easiest way is to look for a linear algebra package for your implementation language. The de facto standard for linear algebra is the LAPACK library, and for this problem you would probably use the dgesv routine. There are library bindings for LAPACK for most languages, if you look hard enough.

Comment: If you want an actual algorithm, you can use LU decomposition with partial pivoting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition.